# Get async result in async.filter() array nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, fs, xml2js

Need to parse some XML files from `mass` array with `file_path` values.
Try to use `async`, `fs`, `xml2js`.
When use single string `file_path` all works perfect. But when I use `aync.filter()` with array I can't understand how I can `return result` from `xml.parseString()`

```
const fs = require('fs');
const xml2js = require('xml2js');
const async = require('async');

var mass=['/file1.xml','/fil2.xml','/file3.xml',...]

async.filter(mass, async function(file_path, callback){
    if(fs.statSync(file_path)['size']>0){
        fs.readFileSync(file_path, 'utf8', function(err, data) {        
            xml.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
               console.log(Object.keys(result)[0]);
               return result; //need get this result to results array
            })
        }) 
    }
}, function(err, results) {
    console.log(results)
});
```

Who can understand how it works and what I need to change in my code.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to map and filter at the same time. Since your filter condition is synchronously available, use the array `filter` method for that, and then pass that to `async.map`.

You should then call the callback function, that `async.map` provides to you, passing it the result. So don't return it, but call the callback.

The `readFileSync` method does not take a callback like its asynchronous counterpart. It just returns the data.

Also, drop the `async` keyword, as you are not using the `await` keyword at all.

```
async.map(mass.filter((file_path) => fs.statSync(file_path).size > 0), 
    function(file_path, callback){
        var data = fs.readFileSync(file_path, 'utf8');
        xml.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
           console.log(Object.keys(result)[0]);
           callback(null, result);
        }) 
    }, function(err, results) {
        console.log(results)
    });
```

It should be noted however, that since Node now comes with the Promise API, and even the `async/await` extension to that, the `async` module has become much less interesting. Consider using Promises.

```
const promises = mass.filter(file_path => {
    return fs.statSync(file_path).size > 0
}).map(function(file_path) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        const data = fs.readFileSync(file_path, 'utf8');
        xml.parseString(data, function (err, result) {
            console.log(Object.keys(result)[0]);
            resolve(result);
        });
    }); 
});
Promise.all(promises).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: unfortunately `results` is `undefined`. I try to understand Promise API on your example . Thanks!

Comment: `console.log(Object.keys(result)[0]);` works fine. But how I can push `result` from parse to `results` array of filter/map function

Comment: Corrected a mistake (`asyc.filter` should be `async.map` and callback should pass a null value) and added a Promise version.

Comment: It's work great with promises! I really need to learn Promise methods! Thank you so much @trinton!